# DataBind to ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource

My program should read and process data from legacy flat files.

I read the data into `private ICollection<transaction> transactions;`

```
public class transaction
{
    public int transactionNum;
    public DateTime transactionDate;
    public int orderNum;
    public string customerName;
    public Decimal amount;
}
```

How do I create a `DataSource` to this `ICollection<T>` (or a LINQ query of it), so that I can `DataBind` several control values to it?

Note: I have minimal LINQ knowledge.  In the past, I could just drag a database table into my application.

Comment: DataSource for what? Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: I don't understand the question, you can already bind it to a control in winforms or ASP.NET. It just needs to implement `ICollection`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.idatasource.getviewnames.aspx

Comment: On the ASP.NET form, I have a `CheckBoxList` named `customerCheckL`.  Upon loading the data file, the code should populate `customerCheckL.Items` with the list of distinct customer names.  How do I do that?  `customerCheckL.DataSource = ???`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> On the ASP.NET form, I have a CheckBoxList named customerCheckL. Upon
>   loading the data file, the code should populate customerCheckL.Items
>   with the list of distinct customer names. How do I do that?
>   customerCheckL.DataSourceID = ???

That makes more sense. You could implement an `EqulityComparer<transactions>` class which compares by customer:

```
public class TransactionCustomerComparer : IEqualityComparer<transaction>
{
    public bool Equals(transaction x, transaction y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.customerName == y.customerName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(transaction obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return int.MinValue;
        return obj.customerName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

(Note that you can use this method in all `Enumerable` methods that allow to pass a custom comparer)

Then you can use `Distinct` to get a unique list. You just have to set the `DataSource`, `DataTextField` and  `DataValueField`  and `DataBind` the `CheckBoxList`.

```
var customerComparer = new TransactionCustomerComparer();
customerCheckL.DataSource = transactions.Distinct(customerComparer);
customerCheckL.DataTextField = "customerName";
customerCheckL.DataValueField = "transactionNum";
customerCheckL.DataBind();
```